# onAfterRendering call before data views loaded, use factory

Tags: javascript, view, model, factory, sapui5

I have a typical Controller and a JS-View.

In the View I used a factory function to build an item list like this:

```
new sap.m.List(this.createId("myList"), {
    noDataText: "{i18n>textNoData}",
    items: {
        path: "/PathToServiceApp",
        sorter: new sap.ui.model.Sorter("Date"),
        factory: this.itemFactory.bind(this)
    }
});

this.itemFactory: function (sId, oContext) {
    ...
},
```

and in the Controller I used the `onAfterRendering` live cycle method:

```
onAfterRendering: function () {
    ...
}
```

Problem: `onAfterRendering` is called before the View gets data from the path "/PathToServiceApp".

Any idea how to call `onAfterRendering` after data is loaded and DOM elements are created?

Answer (score 2):

`onAfterRendering` will be called after **each** rendering.

In the function you cannot count on the data being there as one rendering might occur before the data is loaded if the Model is loading data asynchronously.

If the data of the path used in the binding (in your case `/PathToServiceApp`) changes, the controls in the binding will be refreshed and `onAfterRendering` will be called again.

If you want to modify the list items after they get rendered, you should hook into their `onAfterRendering` function instead of the Controller one.

Comment: ok, maybe You know how to get data synchronously (i use OData model)? Thx for help

Comment: It doesn't look that way for the ODataModel.

Answer (score 0):

Controls that are based on `ListBase`, have an `UpdateFinished` event that fires after items binding is updated and processed by the control. If you want to run code after the data is loaded in your `List`, it's best to hook this event up to that logic.